# Is it possible to capture every server requests resulting in a 404?

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are currently capturing the requested URL when someone gets redirected to our 404 page. However, this does not allow us to see reports on things like broken images. Is it possible to get this information in SiteCatalyst, for example by taking the URL of every server request that received a 404 response and store it in a a variable? What would be a sensible way to go about this? I Googled and couldn't find anything

I want to be able to pull a report on every broken URL reference of a site and the page it happened on...

Comment: You can do this with a [Data Source](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/datasources/)

Comment: Basically you have to write your own server-side script to parse your server request logs and send to SiteCatalyst as a data source.. but if you're just looking for a list of the urls, is it really necessary to go that far? why not just stop at the point where you extracted them from your server logs..

Comment: I see, so basically you need to get this info from the server logs. I was hoping the server responses were stored in some JS variable somewhere.

Comment: No. There are a few (questionable/hacky) ways to *infer* 404 status for a couple of resource types, but there is no 100% reliable way to do it for all (or any one) of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your webserver, says Apache, for instance, to redirect an 404 error to a specific web page, says:

`ErrorDocument 404 /my_path/not_found.html`

Then you can configure your dispatch inside the not_found.html, in a embedded JavaScript.

Here's how to configure apache to redirect this error request:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html